# Counting files per owner recursively

Tags: 12.04, bash

From an entire directory structure I would like to output all the owners and how many files belong to each owner.

I would like an output like this:

```
+-------+-----+
| alex  |   3 |
| liza  | 345 |
| harry | 564 |
| sally |  23 |
+-------+-----+
```

How can I do this in `bash`?

Answer (score 2):

This won't draw the pretty lines but...

```
#!/bin/bash

for _user in `ls /home`
do
    _count=`ls -R /home/$_user/ | wc -l`
    echo "$_user = $_count"
done
```

Comment: thanks so much! im actually using cygwin to do this on a windows file server,

Comment: This will be inaccurate as the `ls -R` output will have a blank line for each new directory. Parsing `ls` is usually unreliable. Also you're missing out on hidden "dot" files (`.hidden`).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use `find` and `wc` in a for-loop:

```
users=`getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}'`
for user in $users
do
    echo -n "file count for $user: "
    find / -user $user -type f | wc -l
done
```

Notes:

- `find` is recursive by default.
- You may want to prepend the `find` line with `sudo` in order to have the privileges for reading all directories. Or run the complete script as root.
- It now limits to listings of *files* by the `-type f` filter. Remove that if you want to count directories too.
- It's not terribly efficient, as it's first listing all names, while `wc -l` then just counts the number of newlines.

---

Parsing `ls -R` is inaccurate for several reasons. Firstly, it lists directory entries twice. Secondly, it leaves an additional blank line while it descends into directories. Thirdly, you'll need to pass `-a` to count hidden files. And finally, it won't be possible to filter directories.

See the demo below:

```
mkdir d1 d2 d3
touch a b c d1/a d2/a d3/a
tree
.
├── a
├── b
├── c
├── d1
│   └── a
├── d2
│   └── a
└── d3
    └── a

3 directories, 6 files

find . | wc -l
11

find . -type f | wc -l
7

ls -R | wc -l
16

ls -R | cat -   # to show why the number was 16
.:
a
b
c
d1
d2
d3

./d1:
a

./d2:
a

./d3:
a
```

Comment: The for-loop requires a list of user names, but this can be generated based on the directories in `/home/` by replacing the hard-coded user names with `$(ls /home)`.

Comment: @iBelieve Users with a home folder outside `/home` will not be listed then. And, moreover, a user's home folder does not have to match the username. So, I've added it "the right way" by using `passwd`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Linux quota system. You'll have to enable it first and get it initialized, but it will require a lot less resources for creating a report.

1. Install the `quota` package.
2. Add the `usrquota` mount option to the file system in `/etc/fstab`.
3. Remount or reboot the file system.
4. Do the initial quota scan by running `quotacheck -avug`.
5. Run `repquota` to list the usage. The File limits (used) column lists the amount of 'files' per user. However, it's not quite the same as the amount of actual files, but it's the number of [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).

   ```
                           Block limits                File limits
   User            used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace
   ------------------------------------------------------
   root      --   80088       0       0          12025     0     0       
   daemon    --       8       0       0              3     0     0       
   man       --     172       0       0             17     0     0
   ```

To get a new report on a later time, it's only required to run `repquota` and this will run a lot quicker than running `find` all over again!

*Note: it's not needed to set actual quota limits - just use it for reporting.*

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Ed Manet's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/250350/109543), this will print the lines around the file counts:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "+---------------+-------+"
for _user in `ls /home`
do
    _count=`ls -R /home/$_user/ | wc -l`
    printf "| $_user\t| $_count\t|\n"
done
echo "+---------------+-------+"
```

Note that this works by counting the files in each user's home directory, so it can only scan the `/home/` directory, and also it won't work correctly if one user has files in another user's directory.